# Asp.net C# how to make make a breadcrumb index with one different colour

Tags: c#, asp.net, breadcrumbs, foreground

OK asp.net is not my language at all. However I have been asked to modify a predefined site with a breadcrumb index all in blue shades.
This is how it looks like now:
[image]

so now I have the need to change the colour of only one of the items listed in the picture let's say making the foreground yellow....

OK so as I said I am no expert at all or better I don't fully understand how that works.
For what I know each pages is helped in the navigation with the same breadcrumb index which is taken from the web.sitemap file which is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
        <siteMapNode title="Comunicazioni" url="~/SiteMap/Comunicazioni/Default.aspx" description="Comunicazioni verso gli iscritti">
            <siteMapNode url="~/SiteMap/Comunicazioni/IscrizioneCancellazione.aspx" title="Iscrizione Cancellazione" description="Permette di iscriversi o cancellarsi dalla newsletter" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/SiteMap/Comunicazioni/IscrizioniProssimaGara.aspx" title="Iscrizioni alla prossima gara" description="Permette di iscriversi alla prossima gara e vedere chi si e' gia' iscritto" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/SiteMap/Comunicazioni/ProssimeGare.aspx" title="Prossime Gare" description="Mostra l'elenco delle prossime gare" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/SiteMap/Comunicazioni/ProssimoAllenamento.aspx" title="Prossimo Allenamento" description="Mostra quanto il coach ha deciso per il prossimo allenamento" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/SiteMap/Comunicazioni/ElencoTotaleGare.aspx" title="Elenco Totale Gare" description="Mostra le gare per tutto l'anno" />
            <siteMapNode url="~/SiteMap/Comunicazioni/IscrizioneGrugliaschiamo.aspx" title="Iscrizioni alla Grugliaschiamo" description="Iscrizioni alla Grugliaschiamo" />
        </siteMapNode>

        <siteMapNode title="Report" url="~/SiteMap/Report/Default.aspx" description="Informazioni e testimonianze dalle gare">
            ....
        </siteMapNode>

        <siteMapNode title="Altro" url="~/SiteMap/Altro/Default.aspx" description="Informazioni e risorse aggiuntive">
            ...
        </siteMapNode>


        <siteMapNode title="Regolamento" url="~/SiteMap/Regolamento/Default.aspx" description="Regolamento">
            ....
        </siteMapNode>

</siteMapNode>
```

this for the names, for the colour and so on from the style.css file which I will copy here below.

All the information provided above might not be the right one so please before banning this question tell me what is wrong and I will reformulate is properly.
Thanks

```
/*--------------------*
 *  Pagina totale     *
 *--------------------*/
body
{
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("Resources/Pics/background.jpg");
    background-size:cover
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    background-color: #ADFEFF;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-top: 2px solid #B51032;
}
/*-------------*
 *  Header     *
 *-------------*/
#header
{
    border-top: 3px solid #B51032;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B51032;
    height: 10em;
    background-image: url("Resources/Pics/BannerDoratletica.png");
    background-size: cover
}
#header .title
{
    font: 190% Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
    margin-left: .8em;
}
#header .breadcrumb
{
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.8em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    height: 75px;
    width: 306px;
    margin-left: 62px;
}
#header a:link, a:visited 
{
    color: #B51032;
}
#body {
        padding:10px;
        padding-bottom:60px;    /* Height of the footer */
      }
    #footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;            /* Height of the footer */
        background:#6cf;
    }
/*-------------*
 * Navigazione *
 *-------------*/
#navigation
{
    width: 200px;
    top: 11.45em;
    left: 1em;
    width: 13em;    
    position:absolute;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:90%;
}
#navigation ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation li
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ED9F9F;
}
/*--Blocchi superiori--*/
#navigation li a 
{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 0.5em;
    border-left: 12px solid #0000FF;
    border-right: 1px solid #0000FF;
    background-color: #9090FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation li a:hover
{
    background-color: #0000FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#navigation ul ul
{
    margin-left: 12px;
}
#navigation ul ul li
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #711515;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #ED9F9F;
    color: #711515;
}
/*-----Blocchi primari----*/
#navigation ul ul a:link, #navigation ul ul a:visited
{
    background-color: #C2D7FF;
    color: #0000FF;
}
#navigation ul ul a:hover
{
    background-color: #0000FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
/* Main Content */
#content 
{
    margin-top:1em;
    margin-left: 16em;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
h1 {
    font: 150% Arial, Helvetica, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#content p {
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.6em; 
}
#content ul {
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.6em; 
}
```

---EDIT---ADD---

Upon suggestion I have focused on a part. That is the Site.Master file in which I have found that

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" EnableViewState="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink x:name="AAA" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>

                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <ul>
                        </HeaderTemplate>

                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <li>
                             <asp:HyperLink name="AAA" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink> <-------
                                    </li>
                         </ItemTemplate>

                     <FooterTemplate>
                 </ul>
              </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
  </li>
```

If I could access the hyperlink named "AAA" at page load I could change its foreground when equal to a string. Unfortunately the name "AAA" is not accessible from there... Any other way of accessing the repeater in the loop would do anyhow...
Thanks

Comment: Unsure why you're focusing on ASP.Net or C#? If you need to _apply `CSS` styling_ to whatever is _rendered_ then you _can_ (irrespective of how it was rendered or the underlying technology/framework). Depending on what you're going for, your question maybe overly broad if you need to involve server side code for dynamic styling (you'll need to understand how that works).

Comment: OK thank you for keeping me on the right way (I hope). Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too difficult. Don't refer it with the name but add a OnPrerender event.

```
 <asp:HyperLink  OnPreRender="Unnamed_PreRender" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

then in the event you can do:

```
protected void Unnamed_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = ((HyperLink)sender).NavigateUrl;

    if (str.Contains("XXX")
        ((HyperLink)sender).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

where XXX is part of the name of the url.